# Landscape - Inavlid login credentials. Please try again

Tags: juju, maas, openstack, cloud, landscape

I just conjured up Landscape, following the instructions [there](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/cloud/autopilot) and when I try to login in the webmin, this error appears: **Invalid login credentials. Please try again.**

Isn't it supposed to be the account created?

P.S: These machines are running in K**VM**.

Whether you need more info, I'll deliver

Comment: Ok, I found out why that happens and it's a BUG. If your password contains a dollar sign, the system stores the password as a plain variable. And the password is cut by the dollar sign. Example: If your password is Dollar$ign, then your password becomes Dollar.

Answer (score 1):

Answer from the submitter.

> Ok, I found out why that happens and it's a BUG. If your password
>   contains a dollar sign, the system stores the password as a plain
>   variable. And the password is cut by the dollar sign. Example: If your
>   password is Dollar$ign, then your password becomes Dollar.